# Enum constant in mybatis's sql query

Tags: java, sql, mybatis

I need to reference enum constant in query. I have tried next example

```
<select=...>
  select * from tableA where value = @MyEnum@Value.tostring()
</select>
```

but it simply insert `@MyEnum@Value.tostring()`  value. Also I have tried

```
#{@MyEnum@Value.tostring()}
```

but it is treated as query parameter. So how can I use enum constant in query?

PS  value column is varchar

Comment: Did you ever resolved this? I used a fake parameter, but I would like to fed the query with the actual value of an enum.

Comment: I've investigated it. It doesn't possible to do this, but you can use choose/when tags to test if some parameter equals to enum values

Answer (score 6):

If you want to access any enum constant in MyBatis you should use this form:

Given enum:

```
package org.sample.domain;

public enum Currency {
    USD("$"), YEN("Y"), PLN("zl");

    private String symbol;

    Currency(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    public String getSymbol() {
        return this.symbol
    }
}
```

When you want to use any attribute of your enum.

Then you have to use this form in you xml file:

```
<select id="report" resultMap="resultMap">
    SELECT *
    FROM invoices
    WHERE currency_symbol = '${@org.sample.domain.Currency@USD.getSymbol()}'
</select>
```

MyBatis is injecting value without any quotes therefore you have to enclose it in quotes.

Tested with MyBatis 3.3.1

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are asking a question about using Java with MyBatis?  I'm not sure what the `@MyEnum@` notation is.

In any case, here is how you do what you are asking with MyBatis using Java (I don't know if the MyBatis.NET version has another way to do it.)  I have tested this with MyBatis-3.1.1:

```
<select id="getSomeObjectByValue" resultType="SomeObject" parameterType="MyEnum">
  SELECT *
  FROM tableA
  WHERE UPPER(value) = #{param1.toString()}
</select>
```

"param1" is the default name of the first parameter passed to MyBatis (I think), but when there is only one parameter being passed in, you can give it a different name, so something like this will also work:

```
<select id="getSomeObjectByValue" resultType="SomeObject">
  SELECT *
  FROM tableA
  WHERE UPPER(value) = #{p.toString()}
</select>
```

Notice that I could leave the parameterType off as well and it still works.

Comment: I want statically define enum constant string value in query(I don't want to use simple string like 'somesrting' in query because it can be cnaged). So if I change value of my enum constant, I will have not to change this value in mapper file. Also, passing this value as parameter to query is not a good idea

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a statically defined enum constant or how that differs from my solution. In my example, I'm passing the enum to the query, not a string, then I extract the enum string value in the MyBatis query with `toString`. If you change the value of the enum constant, you will not have to change the mapper in my solution (though the db value would also have to change).  The Mapper interface for my call would be `SomeObject getSomeObjectByValue(MyEnum enum)`.  I have a working example in koan23 of my MyBatis Koans if that helps: https://github.com/midpeter444/mybatis-koans

Comment: Down voted answer, because it does not answers the question plus the tone used.

Answer (score 0):

Only an appreciation:

If you want to use it into a <if test="..."> you also can do the following:

```
<if test="enumParam == @the.enum.pack.MyEnum@VALUE">
    ...
</if>
```

And works fine.